# ReactJS Promise logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, jsx

So I can't figure out this piece of logic regarding a promise in a React component using a js Promise className callback. So what I'm doing is creating a grid item inside a grid and depending on the content of it change the class names "height2" or "width2". So you can see the function "get_image_dimensions" which is called from the "class_name" function when an image is found which is then appended into a string based on the return. But the issue is obviously it's a asynchronous so it will keep running and by the time it gets to the return in the "class_name" function. The reason I can't get around this with a callback is because it's a react component and being called via jsx. If anyone could help that would be great.

If I can clarify anything please let me know.

You can see the code here:

```
import React from 'react';

class GridItem extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className={this.class_name()}>{this.get_value()}</div>
        );
    }

    class_name(){
        let new_class;
        let pin = this.props.pin;
        let promises = [];

        if(pin.type == "text"){
            var length = pin.value.length;
            if(length > 200) new_class += "width2";
            if(length > 500) new_class += "height2";
        }else if(pin.type == "image"){
            var img_promise = this.get_image_dimensions(pin.value).then(function(img){
                let w = img.width,
                    h = img.height;

                if(w>h){
                    new_class += "width2";
                }else if(w<h){
                    new_class += "height2";
                }
            })

            promises.push(img_promise);
        }else if(pin.type == "embed"){
            new_class += "width2 height2"
        }
        return `draggable-section__item draggable-section__item--masonry pin-type-${pin.type}${new_class ? (' '+new_class) : ''}`;
    }

    get_value(){
        let pin = this.props.pin;

        if(pin.type == "text"){
            return <span>{pin.value}</span>;
        }else if(pin.type == "image"){
            return <img src={pin.value}/>;
        }else if(pin.type == "embed"){
            return <iframe src={pin.value}></iframe>;
        }
    }

    get_image_dimensions(url){
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            var img = new Image()
            img.onload = function(){
                resolve(img)
            }
            img.src = url
        })
    }
}

export default GridItem;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are mixing sync code with async code.  To fix it you need to return `draggable-section__item draggable-section__item--masonry pin-type-${pin.type}${new_class ? (' '+new_class) : ''}`; for every if statement. And return the draggable section **only** when the promise has been resolved. Also you should check [async/await](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/), which is another way to work with promises.

```
class_name(){
    let new_class;
    let pin = this.props.pin;
    let promises = [];

    if(pin.type == "text"){
        var length = pin.value.length;
        if(length > 200) new_class += "width2";
        if(length > 500) new_class += "height2";
        return `draggable-section__item draggable-section__item--masonry pin-type-${pin.type}${new_class ? (' '+new_class) : ''}`;
    }else if(pin.type == "image"){
        this.get_image_dimensions(pin.value).then(function(img){
            let w = img.width,
                h = img.height;

            if(w>h){
                new_class += "width2";
            }else if(w<h){
                new_class += "height2";
            }
            return `draggable-section__item draggable-section__item--masonry pin-type-${pin.type}${new_class ? (' '+new_class) : ''}`;

        })

    }else if(pin.type == "embed"){
        new_class += "width2 height2"
        return `draggable-section__item draggable-section__item--masonry pin-type-${pin.type}${new_class ? (' '+new_class) : ''}`;
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks. An issue with this is when returning inside of the promise in the "image" section this means that the class_name function doesn't return but the promise inside does. Is there a way to return out of the scope of the promise then function? @Hosar

Comment: The return is inside the "then" statement so it will return until the promise is resolved. With async/await you can do as your previos example. var img_promise = await this.get_image_dimensions(pin.value);

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up using was the componentDidMount function to call the class_name function to then populate the state property then on the render function output the class name of the state